# How to add an icon to a custom display type in RViz?

Tags: ros, librviz, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a custom display type for RViz (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/oculus_rviz_plugins)) and I would like to have an icon displayed, when I browse for it in RViz.

In the above link, I see that there is a OculusDisplay.png in the directory `icons/classes/..`, but I can not figure out, how to link this. Does anybody know how this is done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213971/how-to-add-an-icon-to-a-custom-display-type-in-rviz?/) by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2015-07-17

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I can tell, that's it, you've essentially figured it out.

For a custom display I put together, I just copied my png to the `icons/classes/` directory, with the same name as the Display (I believe as it's found in the `plugin_description.xml` file).

With that done, it just worked.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2015-07-17**:
lol, it's as easy as that. I forgot to change the name of the icon according to my display type, how silly.